# how to set Maximum upload size to 4GB

Tags: .net-3.5, web-config, httpruntime

please look at the screen shots[image: web.config]

[image: error when i executed]

i need to set upload file size upto 4GB

also this is my 3.5 web app why it is shown that version information as v2.0

is there any mistake in my config?

help me guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my opinion you never allow 4gb to upload at once, use segments.  i suggest you to read following links, which has awesome explanation.

1. [Large File Uploads in Asp.net - Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx)
2. [Dark side of File Uploads.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx)

Suggestion :

1. Try some flash/silverlight based uploads (Telerik has support of silverlight upload) or [SwfUpload](http://swfupload.org/)
2. try to re-think about the architecture, how you are going to save 4gb+ data for each user? .

you can set maxRequestLenght attribute, but setting this value to higher, will lead to hacker to crazy things. and your server will get load.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size you can set in ASP.NET is 2097151Kb = 2Gb. If you need to upload files larger than 2Gb you must implement resumable upload interfaces and upload files with segments.

refer this "http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/upload/resumable_upload"